# Box w/ `float:left` is going underneath instead of left to the next available spot

Tags: html, css, css-float

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/bDUnW/) seems like it should be easy, but I can't get it to work :/
The total width of all the elements is less than 100%, so why dont they all fit nicely together next to each other?

**edit** sorry if I wasn't clear. Why does the 3rd blue `.square` go underneath and stay on the right -- instead of being pushed back to the left to underneath the 1st blue `.square`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="square"></div>

    <div class="bigsquare"></div>

    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
</div>

.outer {position:absolute;width:80%;left:10%;height:100%;border:solid black 2px;
}
.square {
    height: 16%;width: 19%;border-radius: 0px;border:solid 1px #262626;float: left;margin:0px;overflow: hidden;position: relative;padding:0px;background-color:blue;
}

.bigsquare { height: 50%;    width: 57%;border-radius: 6px;background-color:green;border:solid 0px #262626;float: left;    overflow: hidden;position: relative;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Comment: Fit nicely together? You'll have to be more specific.

Comment: I don't see the problem in Firefox. Which browser are you using?

Comment: firefox...why does the 3rd blue square not on the left side, but its on the right?

Comment: Dude, what you are trying to achieve? Do you want to achieve that the blue rectangles will align up, and the green one "bounces" up? Like you click on it or hover over and it becomes green and big, the small blue rectangles will aling to respscting the green one?

Comment: On the first line there is no room after the 2nd blue square. Why does it go underneath instead of to the left side again????

Comment: **Simpler demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/bDUnW/5/

Comment: I get the impression that you misunderstand how float works.  I'm guessing because I'm unclear on your exact desired result, but I think float alone can't do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED:

"Float: left" doesn't make them the element line up to the left margin, they go as far left as they can until they meet another element to block them. In this case the blue divs float left until they meet the green div.

You could use absolute positioning or arrange as 3 "columns": left col with blue div; middle col with blue divs, green div, blue divs; and last col with blue divs

Update 2:

Maybe if you think of them as building blocks it might help. The blue-green-blue fits across the top row. The next blue doesn't so it moves down.It tries to go over to the left margin but the green block is in the way and it can't go *through* the green block. Does that make sense?

Comment: Nope, sorry but that's not it

Comment: I've made the squares small enough to prove the point, there is extra room in the outer div.
Take the borders out, does that solve it? no

Comment: I answered before you edited your answer with more info - All you'd asked was for them to "fit nicely together" so I assumed you were trying to fix the squares that were out of alignment.

Comment: Why don't you make the .outer width 100% and remove the bigsquare border radius.I am not sure I understand your question corectly

http://jsfiddle.net/meetravi/bDUnW/1/

Comment: Why does the 3rd Square remain on the right side and not go to the left?

Comment: I've changed my answer to address your actual issue

Comment: Think of them as sliding to the left in the order that they are in the code.  So first a blue one, then the green, then another blue.  Then the third blue can't fit on that line, so goes down to the next.  Slide it to the left and it will hit the green square and stop.

Comment: @MestekWebmaster, Does the '4th' div go down and then left and 'sees' the green div in the way of its sliding leftward? (to put in lay terms)

Comment: @iight if you are referring to the one that has white space to its left, even if the last 1 px of the green square is in its way it will block the blue div.

Comment: I completely agree, but shouldn't there be room for it? after all, the first blue square fits. If you would change the bigsquare to a smaller height (10%), then everything balances

Comment: @iight if you make your green div smaller e.g. 47% then it no longer stops that block (I've made that block red so we can discuss it easier) and it cal float all the way to the left margin... but it doesn't float UP so you will still have white space, try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/bDUnW/8/

Comment: Sorry, but that is not the 3rd square that isn't going left, this http://jsfiddle.net/bDUnW/9/  on is the problem

Comment: @iight You've totally misunderstood how float works. As I've explained in my answer, floating elements will only float until they meet another element to stop them. Think of them as solid objects. You keep pushing them over to the left until you run out of space in the top row, so the next block moves down and across but it can't move through the green block so it stops there. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you, I understand what you're saying...It moves down and then left, (not like a typewriter where you bring it to the left and then it scrolls down to the next line)..Damn, I guess this can't work

Comment: @iight Nope, not that way. But you could make 3 floating columns like I suggested in my answer... a quickly thrown together demo but you'll need to work out the exact widths (and remember the border will throw your calculations out like I said originally): http://jsfiddle.net/bDUnW/10/

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately This won't work for what I am using it for because the page loads dynamically so I need to just have then all in one container. I appreciate your insights though!

Comment: @iight I believe FluffyKitten answered for me, and it looks like you understand it now.

Comment: @iight Afraid javascript or a dynamic language to calculate absolute positioning is the only thing I can think that would work in that case. Could you accept my answer seeing as it's right & helped even if it wasn't the answer you wanted :)